# Inject HTML into nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm wanting to inject some HTML into a webpage when a user hits `/redirected` and show the rest of the page as normal. At the moment these directives are just showing the normal index.html without the injected HTML. Is there a way to do this?

```
server {
  server_name example.com default_server;
  root /var/www/website/dist/;

  location ~* /redirected$ {
    sub_filter "<body class=\"dark-text\">" "<body><div>You have been redirected here</div>";
    sub_filter_once on;
    rewrite ^/redirected$ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `rewrite ^/redirected$ /index.html;` to `try_files /index.html;`. Basically you don't want to redirect but you want to show the file

Comment: @TarunLalwani That did it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `rewrite ^/redirected$ /index.html;` to `try_files /index.html;`.

Basically you don't want to redirect but you want to show the file